# Как сделать поворот объекта при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

Есть небольшой кораблик и четыре кнопки: налево, направо, вверх, вниз. Как при нажатии на кнопку поворачивать корабль один раз в соответствующую сторону?

*пробовал через `object:rotate(deltaAngle)`, получается, что при каждом нажатии на кнопку корабль вновь поворачивается, что мне не нужно*

Возможно задать фиксированный поворот типа "я нажму на кнопку вверх, а потом еще раз, но ты в первый раз повернешься в позицию "на север", а во второй раз проигнорируешь, ведь ты уже повернут на север"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При повороте запоминайте позицию.
При следующем нажатии на кнопку смотрите позицию, и если она не та, что нужно - игнорируйте.

Answer (score 1):

Если  кораблик - объект, то у него нужно задать свойство "Направление". И прорисовывать уже в зависимости от этого свойства. Стрелками нужно только установить  это значение (1,2,3 или 4 ). Потом рисовать. Можно создать изначально 4 повернутых объекта (картинки) и использовать их или поворачивать один объект из исходного состояния на нужное количество градусов.

Comment: А как задать это свойство, можно поподробнее?

Comment: Пока что, я придумал только два новых решения: 1. вместо четырех проверок на каждую кнопку задать четыре значения угла (angleLeft, angleRight, etc.), а потом просто вставлять в функцию кнопки; 2. написать вообще новую функцию с проверками -- `ship:aniRotate(direction)`, где direction -- одно из четырех направлений.

Comment: да вам можно и не спрашивать тут такие мелочи, все-таки на SO рассматриваются решения и ошибки,  с которыми трудно справиться самому.

Comment: Спасибо, но я правда сначала не мог понять, как это реализовать. Таки выделю первый ответ как верный и покончим с этим.